# Inconsistent quality on different sides of the print - Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3

Fairly new Creality Ender 3.  Seems like everything is leveled and snug, belts tightened.  However, some of the sides are coming out stringy.  See the image of this simple dome - you can see some of the areas on the right are pretty nice, but other side is stringy.  Similar story on XYZ cube - e.g. X comes out pretty well, but its opposite side is stringy and separated.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This looks like over extrusion, have you calibrated the extruder steps per mm?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! While you state the belts are tight, did you ensure all of the rollers move freely? If you are getting bad results on the Y-axis, I'd ensure the bearing rollers under the bed are moving freely. You don't give a print orientation (a picture of the calibration cube would be good here) of which direction is which in the above image, so have to figure from what you state in the question as to the rough side being associated with the Y-axis.

Comment: Which side of the print was the cooling fan on?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions/questions.  Answers in order. <br/> PerplexedDipole, yes, verified that 100mm uses precisely that much filament.  <br/> Paulster2, rough sides are only the opposites of Y and X, which is find very puzzling.  Checked the rollers again, they seem fine.  user77232, the cooling fan is the standard position, which is the right side of the extruder.  I had a suspicious about the fan, but turning it off makes no difference!  Bottom line, still baffled :-/